# Передача двух чисел в разные массивы

Tags: c#

Пользователем вводятся два числа через пробел. Каким образом их можно разделить и отправить в различные массивы? Например, ввод: 23 78 ; Число 23 отправляется в массив номер 1, число 78 отправляется в массив номер 2

Comment: Что означает «отправляется»?

Comment: Ну это грубо написано, по-другому вот так:  massiv1[i]=23; massive2[i]=78;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разделить ввод на числа просто:

```
var inputLine = Console.ReadLine();
var parts = inputLine.Split();
var numbers = parts.Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Теперь у вас список из двух (в идеале) чисел, обращайтесь к ним по индексу, и кладите куда хотите:

```
a1[i] = numbers[0];
a2[i] = numbers[1];
```

---

Обратите внимание, что юзер вполне может ввести с клавиатуры не обязательно два и не обязательно числа. Если вам нужно этот случай отловить и сделать что-то осмысленное, вам понадобится дополнительная логика в коде.

Comment: Это я олимпиадные задания разбираю, вряд ли там будут вводить буквы)

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH: А, это да, если олимпиадное задание, там проверять формат ввода не нужно.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH: Пожалуйста!